# Unalbe to boot on Ubuntu from a hard drive after changing computer

Tags: boot, 20.04, hard-drive

I have a hard drive with Ubuntu 20 (and grub) installed on it. Using my old Laptop, I can boot on Ubuntu without issues.
However, I now have a new Laptop with Windows 10 on it and I cannot manage to boot onto Ubuntu.

So far I have disabled fast boot in the BIOS, I have tried to enable legacy boot which now shows the HDD in the boot menu but still boots to Windows when I choose the HDD.

What should I do to be able to boot on my HDD's Ubuntu

Comment: Better to install fresh.

Comment: Windows is now UEFI boot (since 2012) unless you manually installed in old BIOS mode. Is old drive UEFI or BIOS boot? Best if both are UEFI boot. You may be able to just reinstall grub, but probably better to follow ChanganAuto's suggestion of new install in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Although my UEFI doesn't have you can disable `fast boot` in the `UEFI` (many people still call it `BIOS`, which is incorrect). You can disable `Secure Boot` in the `UEFI`.
Disable 'fast startup' in Windows.(edited the above after comment of @oldfred) 
That aside, there are 2 simple solutions:
(1) Boot from bootable usb-stick with `Ubuntu` on it. (If you still have that, if not make 1 with `Balena Etcher`, `Rufus` or `Ventoy`.) Go to the `terminal` and install `Grub`. The command is `sudo apt install grub`.
(2)Install `Grub2Win` in `Windows`. As the name kinda says it is `grub` but then for `Windows` (Grub4Win would be a better name in my opinion). Open the program and let it search for operating systems. Then make it the default `bootloader`. 
In both cases, after a reboot you should see a grub menu.
Both systems should be installed in the same mode. Or both UEFI, or both Legacy mode.

Comment: Most UEFI have a fast boot setting. Fast boot assumes no system changes, so UEFI/BIOS does not scan system for hardware which is then on drive for operating systems to use. Windows has fast startup which is a form of hibernation.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you for clearing this. I edited my answer.